# How to georeference layers

Tags: qgis, shapefile, georeferencing

I have this problem clearly shown in the image, I want to overlap the two layers, how can I do that? Both the two images are in EPSG:4326.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that are both correctly projected? They  _should_ overlap already.

Comment: @HyPhens I'm not sure, how can I check it?

Comment: Maybe if you use the reproject layer tool from the processing toolbox. Maybe that will fix the  it.

Comment: Quickest way to a fix is to post both of your shapefiles. Note the coordinates in your screen shot are not EPSG:4326.